# High CPU usage on elasticsearch nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, cpu

we have been using a 3 node Elasticsearch(7.6v) cluster running in docker container. I have been experiencing very high cpu usage on 2 nodes(97%) and moderate CPU load on the other node(55%). Hardware used are m5 xlarge servers.
There are 5 indices with 6 shards and 1 replica. The update operations take around 10 seconds even for updating a single field. similar case is with delete. however querying is quite fast. Is this because of high CPU load?
2 out of 5 indices, continuously undergo a update and write operations as they listen from a kafka stream. size of the indices are 15GB, 2Gb and the rest are around 100MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more information to find the root cause:

1. All the ES nodes are running on different docker containers **on the same host or different host?**
2. Do you have resource limit on your ES docker containers?
3. How much heap size of ES and is it 50% of host machine RAM?
4. Node which have high CPU, holds the 2 write heavy indices which you mentioned?
5. what is the refresh interval of your indices which receives high indexing requests.
6. what is the segment size of your 15 GB indices, use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-segments.html to get this info.

**What all you have debugged so far and is there is any interesting info you want to share to find the issue?**

Comment: All the containers are on separate hosts,  there is no resource limit, the heap size is nearly 50% of RAM, yes those nodes have 4 shards and 4 replicas of the heavy indices, I didn't configure any refresh interval, it should be the default one(I'm not aware of it), segment size gave me a huge list which probably I can't attach here. If needed, I'll put the screenshot.